# Android: Giving Authors of Support Libraries Recognition

Tags: android, licensing

To those who have published their apps on Google Play:

What's the proper protocol for recognizing the authors of support libraries you've included in your app?

Comment: The library you use should include this kind of information. If it doesn't , then there isn't.

Comment: This question is off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, I list all of open source libraries in a listview, and link to their Github repo. Like this

[image]

Download my app ([Bing daily wallpaper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.groidify.bingdaily)) to see how it looks.

Answer (score 2):

In the application that my company has published we use a handful or 3rd-party libraries.  We have given credit to authors by including an "Open Source License" screen, accessible from our application menu, that includes:

- The libraries we have used.
- The license terms of the libraries.

For example:

This product includes software developed by Joda.org 
  (http://www.joda.org)

Followed by the terms of the Apache 2.0 license.  Note that this particular license has a clause that requires you to include the licenses text in your software.

In general - the license terms will dictate what you are required to do.